For quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ on a proper scheme, $\operatorname{Ext}^2(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) = 0$
In their book, Görtz and Wedhorn, claim that the derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a proper scheme has the following properties:

abelian
exact coproducts
for all $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G} \in D_{\mathrm{qcoh}}(X)$, $\operatorname{Ext}^2(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) = 0$.

(See Example F.153, Exercise F.31, proof of Theorem 25.127 (=Serre duality).)
How can one see that the last condition holds?
EDIT: Thank you to @Kenta S for pointing out that this does not hold. In fact, I misread the statement in the book. (They claim that the properties hold for the derived category of $k$-modules, which is more reasonable.)

For $X=\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb C}$ don't we have $\mathrm{Ext}^2(\mathcal O,\mathcal O(-3))=H^2(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O(-3))=\mathbb C$?
